# Get Correct keyCode for keypad(numpad) keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting codes **[96..105]** by calling `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` when pressing keys **[0..9]**(digits) on the keypad.
Though these codes correspond to characters: **'a b c d e f g h i'**  instead of **[0..9]**.

***Question:***

I have 3 inputs in the form. User allowed to enter only in the 1-st input. While user press keys on keyboard some function need to filter it and write it to 2-nd input if pressed key is digit otherwise it must write it to the 3-rd input. How it can be corrected?

[My implementation in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/tABDr/)

Comment: I'm getting values between 48 and 57, using your code and Opera as browser.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the `keypress` handler:

```
[somelement].onkeypress = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
}
```

See also: [this W3C testdocument](//www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html)

if you want to use the `keyup` or `keydown` handler, you can subtract 48 from `e.keyCode` to get the number (so `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode-48)`)

[**Edit** 2023/07] A very old answer. Nowadays `keyboardEvent.keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Use `keyboardEvent.key` or `keyboardEvent.code` instead.

```js
document.addEventListener(`keydown`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`control (+) ${evt.ctrlKey}, shift (+) ${
    evt.shiftKey}, alt (+) ${evt.altKey}`);
  console.log(`${evt.key} (code: ${evt.code})`);
}
```

```html
<h2>Press any key</h2>
```

Comment: what does it means e=e || event ?

Comment: In most browsers the key event is sent to the handler. Not so in Internet Explorer. The line means: *take the given event e from the arguments of the handler function, and if that's false or null, use the event of the global object (ie `window`)*.

Comment: +1 to your comment :-) . And your code works greate. but little problem. i will send it after five seconds.

Comment: Why the hell are different keyCodes being used based on the event that was triggered. I'm using the same key on my keyboard!

Answer (score 15):

I fixed the issue using following javascript code. The numpad keys lie between `96` to `105`. but the real numbers are less `48` from the numpad values. Works with keyup or keydown handler.

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) {
  // Numpad keys
  keyCode -= 48;
}
var number = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
```

Comment: Good solution because `backspace` doesn't get picked up using keypress.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this with keydown, if keypress is not workable due to event canceling needs, etc. Use an if() statement with this test:

```
parseInt(event.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) > 47 && parseInt(event.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) < 58
```

OR, with jQuery events:

```
parseInt(event.originalEvent.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) > 47 && parseInt(event.originalEvent.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) < 58
```

These examples assume "event" is the keydown event. keyIdentifier is a hexidecimal number that represents the unicode value for the related char. Using keyIdentifier, numbers from the numberpad / keypad AND the numbers above your QWERTY keyboard will all have the same values, 48 - 57 (U+0030 - U+0039), even with the keyDown event.

Unicode values in the browsers will look like U+0030 or U+002F. Parse this string to only get the hexidecimal value, then use parseInt() with a radix of 16 to convert it to base-10.

Comment: Works great, but only in Chrome (not in FF, IE or Edge - not sure about Safari). `keyIdentifier` was only ever in a draft spec and has since been deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyIdentifier).

Answer (score 2):

Ok. But In Firfox Gecko It doesn't work. I use bellow code and I'm happy with it :)

```
[somelement].onkeypress = function(e){
  var singleChar=e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  console.log(singleChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

event.charCode at onKeyPress return the same code when press a number in keyboard and keypad.
but event.keyCode at onKeyDown (or up) return different code.
=> get char: use event.charCode at onKeyPress event
   event.preventDefault() (or event.returnValue=false on IE) for number use event.keyCode at onKeyDown event

Answer (score 0):

I think a safer way is not assuming the value keys that will be used. You could get the working value by the KeyboardEvent object and access its properties "DOM_VK_*". Let me give you an example.

```
 const kcN0=KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_0;//get the 0 key value (commonly,48)
 const kcN9=KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_9;//get the 9 key value (commonly, 57)
 const kcNPad0=KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD0;//get the NUMPAD 0 key value (commonly,96)
 const kcNPad9=KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_NUMPAD9;//get the NUMPAD 9 key value (commonly,105)
 const kcNPad_L=KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD;//get the key location of NUMPAD (commonly, 3)
```

and evalute the event variable "kbEv"

`let pressKeyCode=(kbEv.which||kbEv.keyCode);
 if( kbEv.location===kcNPad_L && pressKeyCode>=kcNumP0 && pressKeyCode<=kcNumP9 )
        pressKeyCode=kcN0+kcNPad9-pressKeyCode;`

I've only assumed that from 0 to 9 will be sequential in those two disjoint  numerical digit pattern set.