# keyCode values for numeric keypad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, numeric-keypad

Do the numbers on a numeric keypad have a different keycode than the numbers at the top of a keyboard?

Here is some JavaScript that is supposed to run on the keyup event, but only if the keycode is between 48 and 57. Here is the code:

```
$('#rollNum').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) { //0-9 only
        var max = 15;
        var textLen = $(this).val().length;
        var textLeft = max - textLen;
        . . .
```

My problem is that this code only runs in response to the numbers entered at the top of the keyboard, but does not run in response to numbers entered from the numeric keypad.

I'm thinking the answer must be that the numeric keypad has different keyCode values, but how do I find out what those are?

Comment: You could just alert/log e.keyCode and give yourself the answer.

Comment: Here is the guide for every key on the keyboard http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

Comment: They (`e.keyCode`) are different for `keyup` and `keydown` because these events are related to the physical keys and those keys are different. If you use `e.which` from `keypress`, you'll get the same values for both keys.

Comment: Reference for all keycodes ( with demo ) : http://www.codeforeach.com/javascript/keycode-for-each-key-and-usage-with-demo

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The keycodes are different. Keypad 0-9 is Keycode `96` to `105`

Your `if` statement should be:

```
if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) { 
  // 0-9 only
}
```

Here's a [reference guide for keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

---

**-- UPDATE --**

This is an old answer and `keyCode` has been deprecated. There are now alternative methods to achieve this, such as using `key`:

```
if ((e.key >= 48 && e.key <= 57) || (e.key >= 96 && e.key <= 105)) { 
  // 0-9 only
}
```

Here's an [output tester for event.key](https://keyjs.dev/), thanks to @Danziger for the link.

Comment: Wanted to note that this is different in jQuery's .keypress() event, which reports 48-57 for numbers whether they come from the keyboard or numpad.

Comment: Reference for all keycodes ( with demo ) : http://www.codeforeach.com/javascript/keycode-for-each-key-and-usage-with-demo

Comment: you should use KeyValue instead of  keyCode  in keyDown event

Comment: @reyhane 1) the logic here is using `keyup`, not `keydown`. 2) There is no `keyValue` property in a jQuery event.

Comment: 1+ here also key code https://blogs.longwin.com.tw/lifetype/key_codes.html  and demo test here https://speedysense.com/javascript-keyboard-event/ keypress event.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. `e.key` simplifies this a lot. Also, instead of using static charts to find the key codes/identifiers you need, you could check them out by just clicking the actual keys in here: https://keyjs.dev

Comment: Don't use codes unless all your users have the same exact keyboard layout as yourself. Codes identify physical keys, not the character these keys are going to send. Prefer `e.key` which is much more portable. For numeric keypad, use `e.location` to distinguish which part of the keyboard it comes from.

Answer (score 25):

******************* **Don't use KEYCODE !!!!** ******************

The problem with **keyCode** is to avoid the combined keys with the numbers on top of keyboard, we must add a check on the key **"Shift"** and **"Alt"** to avoid special characters such as **e @ & " { }** ...

A simplest solution is to convert **e.key** to a number and check if the conversion gives **NaN**!

```
let key = Number(e.key)
if (isNaN(key) || e.key === null || e.key === ' ') {
  console.log("is not numeric")
}
else {
  console.log("is numeric")
}
```

**Be careful** if e.key is **null** or a **space**, it gives **0** !

```
Number(5)         // => 5
Number('5')       // => 5
Number(null)      // => 0 
Number(' ')       // => 0
Number('chars')   // => NaN
Number(undefined) // => NaN
```

Comment: We can use parseInt except Number then it results NaN when it's space or null.

Comment: One more thing we might beware of keyboard language layout. Some keyboard layouts changed default numeric keys to symbols.

Comment: Good job @AlmasDusal. Test can also become if ( parseInt(e.key) >= 0 ) ...

Answer (score 9):

You can simply run

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

to see the codes of pressed keys in the browser console.

Or you can find key codes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Numpad_keys

Comment: This answer may not be useful if you're using a keyboard without a numeric keypad

Answer (score 6):

*keyCode is different for numbers on numeric keypad and numbers on top of keyboard.*

keyCodes :

**numbers on top of keyboard** ( 0 - 9 ) : 48 - 57
**numbers on numeric keypad**  ( 0 - 9 ) : 96 - 105

JavaScript condition :

```
if((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <=57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <=105)) { 
    // entered key is a number
}
```

Reference for all keycodes ( with demo ) : http://www.codeforeach.com/javascript/keycode-for-each-key-and-usage-with-demo

Answer (score 2):

For the people that want a CTRL+C, CTRL-V solution, here you go:

```
    /**
     * Retrieves the number that was pressed on the keyboard.
     *
     * @param {Event} event The keypress event containing the keyCode.
     * @returns {number|null} a number between 0-9 that was pressed. Returns null if there was no numeric key pressed.
     */
    function getNumberFromKeyEvent(event) {
        if (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) {
            return event.keyCode - 96;
        } else if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
            return event.keyCode - 48;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It uses the logic of the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to some of the other answers, note that:

- `keyup` and `keydown` [differ from `keypress`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630990/4500152)
- if you want to use `String.fromCharCode()` to get the actual digit from `keyup`, you'll need to first normalize the `keyCode`.

Below is a self-documenting example that determines if the key is numeric, along with which number it is (example uses the [`range` function from `lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range)).

```
const isKeypad = range(96, 106).includes(keyCode);
const normalizedKeyCode = isKeypad ? keyCode - 48 : keyCode;
const isDigit = range(48, 58).includes(normalizedKeyCode);
const digit = String.fromCharCode(normalizedKeyCode);
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem; for some reason keyCode for numpad 2 was giving the value b when using String.fromCharCode().

Comment: Or, after your answer is understood: `String.fromCharCode( (e.which > 95 && e.which < 107 ? e.which - 48 : e.which )).match(/\d/);`

Comment: Note: using `range` makes the code less efficient, not just because it's calling another function but because it's unnecessarily creating an array with all those numbers instead of just comparing `>= 96` and `<= 106`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are different and while many people have made a great suggestion of using console.log to see for yourself. However, I didn't see anyone mention event.location that you can use that to determine if the number is coming from the keypad `event.location === 3` vs the top of the main keyboard / general keys `event.location === 0`.  This approach would be best suited for when you need to generally determine if keystrokes are coming from a region of the keyboard or not, `event.key` is likely better for the specific keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key code page in order to find the:

> event.code

to diference the number keyboard.

https://keycode.info/

```
function getNumberFromKeyEvent(event) {
   if (event.code.indexOf('Numpad') === 0) {
      var number = parseInt(event.code.replace('Numpad', ''), 10);
      if (number >= 0 && number <= 9) {
           // numbers from numeric keyboard
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs says the order of events related to the onkeyxxx event:

1. onkeydown
2. onkeypress
3. onkeyup

If you use like below code, it fits with also backspace and enter user interactions. After you can do what you want in onKeyPress or onKeyUp events.
Code block trigger event.preventDefault function if the value is not number,backspace or enter.

```
onInputKeyDown = event => {
    const { keyCode } = event;
    if (
      (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
      (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) ||
      keyCode === 8 || //Backspace key
      keyCode === 13   //Enter key
    ) {
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @.A. Morel I find to be the best easy to understand solution with a small footprint. Just wanted to add on top if you want a smaller code amount this solution which is a modification of Morel works well for not allowing letters of any sort including inputs notorious 'e' character.

```
function InputTypeNumberDissallowAllCharactersExceptNumeric() {
  let key = Number(inputEvent.key);
  return !isNaN(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit cleared @A.Morel's answer. You might beware of keyboard language layout. Some keyboard layouts changed default numeric keys to symbols.

```
let key = parseInt(e.key)
if (isNaN(key)) {
  console.log("is not numeric")
}
else {
  console.log("is numeric")
}
```

Comment: Or just : console.log( parseInt(e.key) >= 0 ? "is numeric" : "is not numeric" )

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `event.key` converted to a number is between 0-9.
So we can create a range array 0-9 by `Array.from(Array(10).keys())` and check the `event.key` is in this range or not.

```
const isNumeric = Array.from(Array(10).keys()).includes(Number(event.key));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**event keyCode values for numeric keypad

```js
function digitOnly(event) {
            var key = event.keyCode;
            if (event.key === '!' || event.key === '@' || event.key === '#'
                    || event.key === '$' || event.key === '%'
                    || event.key === '^' || event.key === '&'
                    || event.key === '*' || event.key === '('
                    || event.key === ')' || event.key === '_'
                    || event.key === '-') {
                return false;
            }

            if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57)
                    || (key >= 96 && key <= 105 || key == 8)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

```html
<div id="phoneDiv">
                <label for="phoneNumberId">Phone<b id="starText">*</b></label> <input
                    id="phoneNumberId" type="tel" name="phoneNumber"
                    placeholder="Enter Phone Number here" maxlength="10" minlength="10"
                    onkeydown="return digitOnly(event)" required>
            </div>
```

**

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to figure out keyCodes easily:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // Displays the keycode of the last pressed key in the body
    $(document.body).html(e.keyCode);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vecvc4fr/