# How do I dynamically auto format a number to American Currency using jQuery only?

Tags: jquery, regex, dynamic, currency, autoformat

I am building a form, and I need to have an textbox where the user can enter prices or fees.

I have seen a form that can do what I am looking for, but I am not sure how to do it.  What I am looking for, is by default, the textbox contains $0.00.  As the user starts to type the number, it acts as follows:  12345678 starts as 0.01 > 0.12 > 1.23 > --- > $123,456.78

It needs to automatically add the commas where needed the and period for the cents only allowing 2 digits on the right side of the period.

It also need to BLOCK the ability to enter a non-numeric character other than the comma and period.  So if the user were to type "a", instead of an "a" being displayed then suddenly removed, I don't even want to be able to see the "a".

Answer (score 0):

I would start by suggesting `<input type="number"/>` to restrict the input to numbers only.  Next, here's the regex to handle two decimal places and commas.

```
var money = number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

Where `number` is the number you would get on keyup.  This should work when called on input.

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('keyup', function(e){
    var number = Number($(this).val());
    var money = number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
    $(this).val(money);
});
```

This part is only the beginning.  There's a few conditionals you'd need to put in.  For example, you might want to check for the key that was pressed before allowing a change.  You can do that by checking for [keycodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196945/keycode-values-for-numeric-keypad).

Comment: Okay... I guess I'm confused where to call the variable "money"?

Comment: That's just an example of the regex.  I put the full function below that which uses the regex.

Comment: hmm... I tried adding exactly what you answered, then I changed the input[type="number"] to the actual ID I'm using, then I took out everything and just left a blank page with the textbox (type="number") and your answer, and nothing seems to be changing.

Depending on the location of your answer, it either does nothing different, (won't allow letters due to type="number" but that's it) or as soon as I type a number, it immediately gets deleted

Comment: Ah, first problem is the input is sending into the function as text.  Needs to be converted to a number first.