# Javascript match numeric-keypad numbers failed using keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric-keypad

I tried to restrict input to accept numbers only, it works fine using keyboard numbers but when using (keypad at the right) it failed.

What I tried:

```
$("#NUMBER").keydown(function (e) {
    return( Boolean(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[0-9]+/g)) );
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9qwv5t9j/

**Edit:**
I tested answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196983/3599237 and (Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9qwv5t9j/3/) but its not working.

Comment: Use keypress event instead and btw you should use `event.which` which is normalized in jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/9qwv5t9j/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff: its not working also for my keypad I am confused.

Comment: It works here, check your verrNum lock key maybe... Or this could be depending your keyboard cultur, i don't know... Because anyway, the event to get the char is keypress, keydown/keyup are used to get the key