# Capturing number pad numeric key strokes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, keycode

The following code i have created is allowing me to capture the numeric values entered by the traditional keyboard number keys.

```
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode=8 && event.keyCode=144 && (event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57));"
```

But the code is not capturing the key strokes that comes from the number pad located in the modern keyboards.

Appreciate if any one can help me.

Comment: try `console.log()`ing the event.keyCode to see what is coming in

Comment: That is not valid js; `==` not `=` and how can it be 8 *and* 144? - See [keyCode values for numeric keypad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196945/keycode-values-for-numeric-keypad)

Comment: numpad keys have different keyCodes than the numbers that appear above the letters. Please google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyCode 8   = backspace

keyCode 144 = num lock

keyCode 48 to 57 = 0 to 9

keyCode 96 to 105 = 0 to 9 in numpad

but for me this is completly wrong :

```
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode=8 && event.keyCode=144 && (event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57));"
```

maybe something like that :

```
onkeydown="return ((event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57) || (event.keyCode>=96 && event.keyCode<=105));"
```

Comment: Please do not encourage bad questions by replying with bad answers--OP could easily have discovered the different keycodes with the most basic of google searches.