# Trigger function on number input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input where users are able to write addresses, I want to trigger a javascript function when a number is typed in the text input, how can I achieve it?

EDIT: What I need is to know when a number has been typed, onkeyup via jquery works like a charm, this is what I did:

```
$("#q").keyup((e) => {

        var value = $("#q").val();

        var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]\\d+");

        var succeded = regex.test(value);

        ...
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Add code snippet

Comment: _"how can I achieve it"_ by doing some research, trying things, getting it wrong, looking up solutions (not on SO). StackOverflow should be the _last place_ you come to for a solution.

Comment: You should be able to use Jquery keypress or keydown or keyup events and then check whether numbers are entered or not.Then you can fire respective function.Its better to add some code snippet over here.

Comment: you can check this one:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196945/keycode-values-for-numeric-keypad
it may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keyCode values for numeric keypad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196945/keycode-values-for-numeric-keypad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to use build in KeyEvents, like (keyDown, keyUp, keyPress , etc.).
You can find a lot of information about it.
[KeyboardEvent mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

1. Create html input, and give unique ID.
2. Form JS code take this element.
3. Then just bind event handler to target element.

   ["YOUR_ELEMENT"].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
   console.log(e.value);}, false);

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log('pressing:', e.keyCode);
});

<input type="text" class="js-input">
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jbr78pk8/1)

This will get you started

Answer (score 0):

This will do your job:

```
$('#tbInput').keypress(function(event){

if(event.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
}
else
{
//Your function that you want to trigger.
alert("You pressed a numberic key: " + event.which);
}});
```

You can test it here:
[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rTWrb/526/)