# jquery detecting numpad keypress value

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Correct keyCode for keypad(numpad) keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys)

I'm writing an application that needs to be able to get the value of numbers pressed on the keyboard. I've come up with the following code:

```
    var keyVal = "";
    $(document).on("keydown.xRuleKey", function(e) {
        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (!isNaN(keyChar)) {
            keyVal += keyChar;
        }
    })
```

This works fine for the numbers on the top of the keyboard but when I use the numpad, the characters "`abcdefghi" are returned instead of "0123456789". Is this normal or is my keyboard weird? If it's normal is it safe to simply to set up a key/value pair to translate the letter to it's number equivelant or will that conflict with anything else. I don't think it will conflict with the regular letter keys as they return uppercase characters and the numpad returns lowercase.

Any thoughts? Anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys, there is a link to a great jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/tABDr/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix it, just need subtract 48 from the keyCode if it's on the numpad

Comment: @TryingToImprove You should post that as an answer so HuwD can accept it.  Community!

Comment: @ntgCleaner Yea, you got a point.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments.. :-)

Take a look here : [stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/)…, there is a link to a great jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/tABDr

Hope it worked out okay.. :-)

Comment: everyone deserves their points!