# javascript regex for numpad

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture that pressed key is **0-9** including numbers from numpad. I wrote a function that checks it but  it doesn't work on numpad digits

```
function getKeyVal(e) {
   var order = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
   return /^\s*\d+\s*$/.test(order)
}
```

`String.fromCharcode` return "**a**" from numpad key **1**.

Can anybody help?

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html and many similars. Getting character pressed is much more tricky, so your assuption that String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) is always correct is unfortunatelly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onkeypress handler, or subtract 48 from the keycode. See this question:

[Get Correct keyCode for keypad(numpad) keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys)

Answer (score 0):

[KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated and no longer recommended. [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) should be used. `KeyboardEvent.code` property represents a physical key on the keyboard. `KeyboardEvent.key` property returns the value of the key.

**Examples:**

**`KeyboardEvent.code`:** If `1` is pressed on `Numpad` it will return `Numpad1`.

**`KeyboardEvent.key`:** If `1` is pressed on `Numpad` it will return `1`.

If you want only to get keys from `Numpad` or the `Digit` keys, Check if `indexOf` Numpad/Digit is greater than `-1`. Your function will be as following:

```
function getKeyVal(e) {
  if (e.code.indexOf('Numpad') > -1 || e.code.indexOf('Digit') > -1) {
    return e.key;
  }
}
```

Otherwise simply use `e.key` or function as:

```
function getKeyVal(e) {
  return e.key;
}
```