# Javascript String.fromCharCode returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this Knockout custom binding to validate a text box to contain only English letters. But, it seems like Javascript's `String.fromCharCode` returns wrong values.

For example, the Hebrew letter **"ש"** returns as the English letter "A", and the number "1" from the right numbers pad has returns as "a"...

Here is my Knockout binding:

```
var arrValidKeys = [8, 16, 17, 20, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46];
    ko.bindingHandlers.validateText = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {

                //Regex pattern: allow only (A to Z uppercase, a to z lowercase)
                var englishAlphabet = /[A-Za-z]/g;

                // Retrieving the key from the char code passed in event.which
                var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

                // keyCodes list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781360/114029
                // check that the key is valid with the above Regex
                valueAccessor()($(this).val());

                return ((jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, arrValidKeys) != -1) || englishAlphabet.test(key));
            });

            $(element).on("keyup", function (event) {

                //Regex pattern: allow only (A to Z uppercase, a to z lowercase)
                var englishAlphabet = /[A-Za-z]/g;

                // Retrieving the key from the char code passed in event.which
                var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

                // keyCodes list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781360/114029
                // check that the key is valid with the above Regex

                valueAccessor()($(this).val());

                return ((jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, arrValidKeys) != -1) || englishAlphabet.test(key));
            });

            $(element).on("paste", function (e) {
                var englishAlphabet = /[A-Za-z]/g;
                if (englishAlphabet.test($(this).val()))
                    valueAccessor()($(this).val());
                else
                    e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: `event.keyCode` and `event.which` are the same thing in jQuery - best to use one or the other.  Using both can be confusing.

Comment: Something that might help us is a jsfiddle :)

Comment: I'm working on a jsfiddle for you :)

Comment: A jsfiddle, just for you :) https://jsfiddle.net/2ma9nhn7/

Comment: Seems to work well for me. I've updated the fiddle a bit, because with `paste` it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/2ma9nhn7/2/ What value holds `event.which` if you hit `1` ?

Comment: There are 2 sets of numbers on a desktop keyborad:one on the top of the letters and the other one to the right where the "NumLock" button is. And if I press "1" from the right it translates i into "a", and letters in other languages are also enabled and I want only English letters to be enabled

Comment: I don't have those keys :) Your problem does sound however like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys) post.

Comment: I've tried it at the beginning, but the `keypress` event doesn't fire when pressing the backspace (for delete) button... So I ended up using all 3 events fo this: `keypress`, 'keydown' and `keyup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Jeanluca Scaljeri's suggestion from this post: [Get Correct keyCode for keypad(numpad) keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys)

I updated my code to this:

```
// keyCodes list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781360/114029
var arrValidKeys = [8, /*backspace*/
                    16, /*shift*/
                    17, /*ctrl*/
                    20, /*caps lock*/
                    35, /*end*/
                    36, /*home*/
                    37, /*left arrow*/
                    39, /*right arrow*/
                    46, /*delete*/];

function validateChar(keyCode) {
    //Regex pattern: allow only (A to Z uppercase, a to z lowercase)
    var englishAlphabet = /[A-Za-z]/g;

    //Retrieving the key from the char code passed in event.which
    var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

    //Check that the key is valid with the above Regex
    return ((jQuery.inArray(keyCode, arrValidKeys) != -1) ||     englishAlphabet.test(key));
}

ko.bindingHandlers.validateText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on("keypress", function (event) {
            valueAccessor()($(this).val());
            return validateChar(event.which);
        });

        $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {
            valueAccessor()($(this).val());
            return validateChar(event.which);
        });

        $(element).on("keyup", function (event) {
            valueAccessor()($(this).val());
            return validateChar(event.which);
        });

        $(element).on("paste", function (e) {
            var englishAlphabet = /^[A-Za-z]+$/g;
            var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            if (!englishAlphabet.test(text))
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
};
```

The reason I've added all 3 events (`keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup`) is that `keypress` alone does not fire when pressing the backspace key, and I need it to update a label with knockout observable.

And here is a working jsfiddle link: [https://jsfiddle.net/2ma9nhn7/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/2ma9nhn7/6/)

Comment: Regarding this question, yes, and thank you very much for your help :-) though it does looks like a bit overkill to handle 3 events for this task...

Comment: I guess you'r right. But I'm afraid there are no other options.