# Number pad (10 key) character codes incorrect in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, fromcharcode, numpad

I notice that when I listen for a keypress the character codes show up differently in Chrome and IE. Does anyone know why this is happing?

Chrome:

```
numpad key: 0, String.fromCharCode(48) => "0"
numpad key: 1, String.fromCharCode(49) => "1"
numpad key: 2, String.fromCharCode(50) => "2"
numpad key: 3, String.fromCharCode(51) => "3"
numpad key: 4, String.fromCharCode(52) => "4"
numpad key: 5, String.fromCharCode(53) => "5"
numpad key: 6, String.fromCharCode(54) => "6"
numpad key: 7, String.fromCharCode(55) => "7"
numpad key: 8, String.fromCharCode(56) => "8"
numpad key: 9, String.fromCharCode(57) => "9"
```

IE:

```
numpad key: 0, String.fromCharCode(96)  => "`"
numpad key: 1, String.fromCharCode(97)  => "a"
numpad key: 2, String.fromCharCode(98)  => "b"
numpad key: 3, String.fromCharCode(99)  => "c"
numpad key: 4, String.fromCharCode(100) => "d"
numpad key: 5, String.fromCharCode(101) => "e"
numpad key: 6, String.fromCharCode(102) => "f"
numpad key: 7, String.fromCharCode(103) => "g"
numpad key: 8, String.fromCharCode(104) => "h"
numpad key: 9, String.fromCharCode(105) => "i"
```

I'm using jquery [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) should normalize `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`:

```
$("#input").keypress(function(e){
    console.log e.which, String.fromCharCode(e.which)
})
```

This is different than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918) since it uses vanilla javascript `e.keyCode` instead of jquery `e.which`

I wonder if this has something to do with using a Windows Virtual Machine (Parallels Desktop).

Comment: You might simply want to manually map them instead: for values between 96 and 105, subtract 48 from them (basically, the numpad keys are their respective numeric keys are always 48 apart).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem in IE11 https://codepen.io/imjosh/pen/VbBEKz?editors=1111

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Correct keyCode for keypad(numpad) keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys)