# Converting Javascript Key Code to Char and vice versa

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm working on HTML input filtering, and I have the following situation:

I need to convert keyCodes to chars, but when I'm dealing with Numpad keys I get weird outcome:

```
String.fromCharCode(96) //should be 0 but I recieve "`"
String.fromCharCode(97) //should be 1 but I recieve "a"
String.fromCharCode(98) //should be 2 but I receive "b"
String.fromCharCode(99) //should be 3 but I recieve "c"
String.fromCharCode(100) //should be 4 but I recieve "d"
String.fromCharCode(101) //should be 5 but I recieve "e"
String.fromCharCode(102) //should be 6 but I recieve "f"
String.fromCharCode(103) //should be 7 but I recieve "g"
```

From documentation and from event debugging I can see the following mapping:

```
numpad 0    96
numpad 1    97
numpad 2    98
numpad 3    99
numpad 4    100
numpad 5    101
numpad 6    102
numpad 7    103
```

link: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys/42917149#42917149

Comment: Please show the [MCVE] code you're using, that way we can more easily provide you with a working answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630918/get-correct-keycode-for-keypadnumpad-keys

Comment: What Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? Just execute String.fromCharCode(103) and you'll get an example

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/) table to get char codes.

Answer (score 0):

Might just be a silly mistake. Charcode you should see is 48-57 for the numbers.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  console.log( String.fromCharCode( 48 + i ) );
}
```

See man ascii

Comment: I meant you might be looking at the wrong numbers for the ascii characters. No offence meant :).

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) I was confused between keyCodes and ASCII codes (because String.fromCharCode doc isn't mention anything regarding that)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so accordingly to several sources from the web I should do the following logic:

```
if(keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105){
    keyCode -= 48;
}
```

Wierd that `String.fromCharCode` function docs doens't say anything about it :(