# Press key and runs function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, key

I won't to run this function when user press the backspace (8) or enter(13).

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 8) { //-- or 13
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        x.style.backgroundImage = "-moz-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
        x.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
        x.style.backgroundImage = "-o-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
        x.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(-180deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
    }
});
```

But this code doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: won't or want????  `e.which == 8` is want and `e.which != 8` is won't.

Comment: What's the point of setting the `.backgroundImage` property and then overwriting it three times with other values? I assume you intend to apply all of those gradient settings at once? Probably easier to create a class in your stylesheet and use jQuery to add that class when required.

Comment: i guess she wants to mimic the CSS pattern, where you use the vendor-specific gradient before the original for browsers that don't support linear-gradient by now.

Comment: In css the body have already this property. I want to overwriting this property to change the background.

Comment: @MicheleCastoldi: check my answer, i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `--90deg` to `-90deg` , --90deg is not valid value. and you may use jQuery to set background

Run snippet and hit enter on body, `jquery v1.2.3` is oldest available on snippet i have used it:

```js
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 13) {

    $("body").css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)');
    $("body").css('background', '-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)');
    $("body").css('background', '-o-linear-gradient(-90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)');
    $("body").css('background', 'linear-gradient(-90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

what jQuery version you use?

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
if(e.which == 8 || e.which == 13) { //-- or 13
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    x.style.backgroundImage = "-moz-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
    x.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
    x.style.backgroundImage = "-o-linear-gradient(--90deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
    x.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(-180deg, #004158 0%, #005472 100%)";
     e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmq0215r/

Comment: Why would the change to `.on('keypress')` help? `.keypress()` is equivalent. Can you explain your answer?

Comment: sure, the trick is not .on or .keypress... e.preventDefault() is:) I just used to .on() method to use

Answer (score 0):

[Try keydown instead of keypress](https://jsfiddle.net/gm32f6fp/4/).

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 8) { //-- or 13
        alert('8');
    }
});
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire)