# React: Event handler method for Backspace

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle an event when the user presses the Backspace button.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire), and I guess I can find Backspace key code using

`console.log("Did you delete it? " + e.keyCode);`

but the value of `e.keyCode` is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
define(["react"], (React) => {
  var TypingContainer = React.createClass({
    keypressed(e) {
      console.log("Did you delete it? " + e.keyCode);
    },

    handleChange: function(e) {
      // if (e.keycode == 8)
        console.log("Did you delete it? " + e.keyCode);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            <input
              className="typing-container"
              value={this.state.message}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={this.keypressed}
            />
         </div>
      );
    }
  })

  return TypingContainer;
});
```

Update: With the `onKeyPress` event, I always get 0.

Comment: You should probably listen to a different event if you want to get the key code. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events .

Comment: @FelixKling i have edited my question

Comment: [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated. You should probably be using [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead. With that, `e.keycode == 8` would become `e.key === 'Backspace'`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to listen to the `onKeyDown` event to capture the delete action.
Example:

```
var InputDemo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            message: ''
        };
    },

    onKeyDown: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            console.log('delete');
        }
    },

    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    value={this.state.message}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Running fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7eu41pzz/1/

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your implementation you should use `onKeyUp` which should ensure the value of the input has been modified before the event is fired.

Based on the above answer

```
var InputDemo = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        message: ''
    };
  },
  onKeyUp: function(e) {
    // This would have the current value after hitting backspace.
    if (e.keyCode === 8) { 
     console.log('delete');
     console.log(`Value after clearing input: "${e.target.value}"`)
     // Value after clearing input: ""
    }
  },
  onKeyDown: function(e) {
    // This would have the value set regardless of hitting backspace "test"
    if (e.keyCode === 8) { 
     console.log('delete');
     console.log(`Value after clearing input: "${e.target.value}"`)
     // Value after clearing input: "Test"
    }
  },
  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
        message: e.target.value
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
          <input
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
            onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}
          />
       </div>
    );
  }
});
```

> These events that are triggered when a key is pressed are in the
> following order:
>
> `keydown Event`: This event occurs when the user has pressed down the
> key. It will occur even if the key pressed does not produce a
> character value.
>
> `keypress Event`: This event occurs when the user presses a key that
> produces a character value. These include keys such as the alphabetic,
> numeric, and punctuation keys. Modifier keys such as ‘Shift’,
> ‘CapsLock’, ‘Ctrl’ etc. do not produce a character, therefore they
> have no ‘keypress’ event attached to them.
>
> `keyup Event`: This event occurs when the user has released the key.
> It will occur even if the key released does not produce a character
> value.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is far simpler. You would normally have some initial/default state:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const initialState = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  streetAddress1: '',
  streetAddress2: '',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  postCode: '',
  country: '',
  phone: '',
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = (prop) => (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [prop]: e.target.value || e.target.checked || initialState[prop],
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="first-name"
        value={state.firstName}
        onChange={handleChange('firstName')}
        aria-label="First Name"
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="last-name">Last Name</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="last-name"
        value={state.lastName}
        onChange={handleChange('lastName')}
        aria-label="Last Name"
      />
      <p>{`${state.firstName} ${state.lastName}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-albattani-kgmq1?file=/src/Demo.js