# onKeydown event in react-select

Tags: reactjs, onkeydown, react-select

I am using the react-select vserion 2 component. I want to be able to trigger the OnKeyDown event when someone presses the backspace key.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: Event handler method for Backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442539/react-event-handler-method-for-backspace)

Comment: Either provide code or exact module which you're using.

Answer (score 8):

`react-select` provides a prop `onKeyDown` which you can use as the following example:

```
 const onKeyDown = e => {
    // catch the code of the key pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  };
```

In this function you can catch the `keyCode` of the key pressed.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vnyo3y4q0).

Answer (score 0):

`react-select` no onKeyDown props available.

Consider something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  onKeyDown = () => {
    // your code here ...
    console.log("your code here");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={this.onKeyDown} className="App">
        <Select options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-key-event-khczpp