# How to return an input field back to its default behaviors?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a site that prevents backspace in an input field by default, but for this particular input, I would like to return it to its default behaviors to accept <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

What is the simplest way to do this? Basically I need the opposite of `preventDefault()`.

Update: I added the following message in the comment but thought it's important to the question. So here it is:

Unfortunately, I have no idea how it prevents the <kbd>backspace</kbd>. I'm creating a Chrome extension which injects an input field into the page. Everything works except the <kbd>backspace</kbd>. I tried to find the code where it prevents it but it's impossible.

My code to create the field is this:

```
if(!document.getElementById("input_typing")){
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.id = "input_typing";
        input.tabIndex = 1;
input.style.width = "95%";
        input.focus();
        txts[i].parentNode.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: turn off javascript )

Comment: To be serious - at first give more details ( how it prevents backspace at least )

Comment: Something like $(this).unbind('submit').submit();

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how it prevents the backspace. I'm creating a chrome extension which injects an input field into the page. Everything works except the backspace. I tried to find the code where it prevents it but it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is: there could be an handler attached to the document so that ***site that prevents backspace ***.

I'm not sure of this, but I created a snippet to clarify my idea:

if an event handler prevent the default action on backspace  you may add a new event handler for your newly created input field in order to stop propagation.

```js
//
// Let's assume this is the site handler to prevent backspace
//
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});


//
// your new element
//
if(!document.getElementById("input_typing")){
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.id = "input_typing";
  input.tabIndex = 1;
  input.style.width = "95%";
  input.focus();
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')[0].parentNode.appendChild(input);

  //
  // Add the keydown event handler to stop propagation
  //
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't think there is a solution, but you did it. Thank you so much. I need to remember e.stopPropagation();

Comment: @Johnny I'm glad for you

Answer (score 0):

In Case if it is **JavaScript** file which prevents the backspace :

You can do inline scripting in your page directly after the js file (which contains code to prevent the backspace in input filed) is added.

So that the JS will be included - it will disable backspace.
Post this when you do your inline scripting to enable the previous functionality - your script code will override the included js

In Case if it is **CSS** file which prevents the backspace :

You can use inline css scripting with **!important** at the end of each line so that this will override the existing css.

**Note** : It would be best to add your css/js inline scripting code at the end of the page to provide certainty and avoid confusions.

Comment: You can prevent backspace with CSS? I didn't know that.

What would the inline script look like to enable the previous functionality?

Comment: you just need to add your code in the previous page and map to the input field again.

Comment: suppose say your input (with class="inputField1") previously had 25 characters allowed and now, because of some included js allows only 5 characters, you can do this.

Add code like this to the end of your page

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.inputField1').attr("maxLength",25);
});
</script>`

Comment: You're talking about maxlength. My issue is entirely different. When I press the backspace key, the input field completely ignores it.  I have to use the delete key to delete characters.

Comment: Suppose say your input is with id = "mytextarea" the below code will do the trick for enabling **backspace** when added in inline scripting

`document.getElementById('mytextarea').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 8){
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
    }
}, false);`

Comment: You would be my hero if you could figure this out for me, and BTW, I'm not using jquery, just regular javascript. Thanks.

Comment: please check the code (edited) in the above comment can be of help

Comment: Hmm, your code says if it is backspace, prevent default behaviors and return back. This is my problem, not my solution. I need the opposite. I need the field to return to the default behaviors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire

check here if this helps

Comment: Thanks, Pat. GaetanoM solved my problem. It's amazingly simple.