# character counter - backspace doesn't reflect on characters remaining

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a character counter code that I have. It's showing how many characters remaining.

```
HTML:
<textarea></textarea> <span id='remainingC'></span>

JS:
$('textarea').keypress(function(){

if(this.value.length > 300){
    return false;
}
$("#remainingC").html((300 - this.value.length)+ "/ 300");
});
```

But I have one problem. When I backspace, the number showing doesn't reflect and only when I start writing then the counter updates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `keypress` -> `keydown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.keypress()` does not fire when the backspace is used. You should use the `input` event instead. Also, `Math.max` greatly simplifies your remaining character calculation.

If you want to enforce an actual cap on the number of characters in your `<textarea>`, you could always add the attribute `maxlength="300"`.

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  $('#remainingC').text(
    Math.max(0, 300 - this.value.length) + ' / 300'
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="300"></textarea> <span id='remainingC'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keydown` event instead of `keypress`.

Comment: Should use `keyup` in case the user holds down the key. You want it to reflect the most updated value

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. This gets all the key codes when the user presses something

[jQuery: keyPress Backspace won't fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire)